# Webpack loading CSS into individual <style> tags

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader

I'm currently using the below Webpack config to import and parse the SCSS imports I make in my React components.

The crux of my issue is with the CSS part of the config. Currently, I'm importing SCSS files using their absolute file paths in their relevant React components. However on render, each individual CSS import gets their own `<style>` tag which results in a dozen `<style>` tags littered in the head of my web app. Is there a way to tweak the config such that the outputted CSS goes into one single `<style>` tag? And perhaps follow a specific entry into my app's React loading sequence with:

```
entry: {
  app: [
    '<React Component that's top of the render tree>',
  ],
},
```

I'm able to extract all the CSS into a single file, using the `ExtractTextPlugin` along with the `style-loader` module. However, that is intrinsically different from actually loading the CSS on the client.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.client.base.config');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

config.output = {
  filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
  path: '../app/assets/javascripts/generated',
  publicPath: '/assets/generated/',
};

config.module.loaders.push(
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css',
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
  }
);

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  );
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what is currently happening on the client side:
[image]

I've tried using the [style-loader singleton option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312069/webpack-loading-css-into-individual-style-tags) but it hasn't worked

Comment: how are you using the css, import s from 'aaa.css'? or import 'aaa.css'?

Comment: for .css use 'style-loader' too

Comment: @UXDart import 'aaa.scss'. And yes, Im using a combination of style, css, postcss, and sass loaders in my test

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm trying to bundle all my CSS together based on some inclusion/exclusion rules, and then I can swap them out for different packs of CSS :)

Comment: @Xenyal Ah! Neat idea. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  loader: 'style-loader'
  options: {
    singleton: true
  }
}
```

from https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader

is that what you were looking?

also (see comments) using `style-loader?singleton` can be used directly in older versions.

Comment: This is the correct answer - however, I hope you can make an amendment that for older versions of `style-loader`, doing `style-loader?singleton` is another way to try. Note that inline query will also support objects - but that's only supported under the `webpack-contrib/style-loader` on GitHub

Answer (score 3):

If you are using style-loader v1.0.0, "singleton" option was removed.
You can use "injectType" instead.

```
{
  loader: 'style-loader',
  options: {
    injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
  }
}
```