# How to join styles into single <style> section

Tags: css, vuejs2

So I have about 9 `<style>` tags in my document's `<head>` from different `.vue` files, is it possible to combine them into one ?

Comment: You mean, how to have this done automatically?

Comment: @MrLister Yes, if possible.

Comment: Just curious, why is it even important?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack loading CSS into individual <style> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312069/webpack-loading-css-into-individual-style-tags)

Comment: @Slim It just looks weird and a little ugly when you look at the source code of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine `<style>` tags by hand - you only have to make sure that there are no doubled styles etc.

For example:

```
<style>
  .foo 
   {
    color: green;
   }
</style> 
<style>
  .bar 
   {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

will become:

```
<style>
  .foo 
   {
    color: green;
   }

  .bar 
   {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

For automatically joining I would suggest to use the well known [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) tool with the option [join-styles](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#join-styles).